# Scroll Style using css chrome & firefox

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create custom style (background color, scroll design.. etc) using **css (only)**, which will be visible in both browser( firefox & chrome).

If yes. how can we...?

For Example: I have some css: please apply some css

```
div.scroll {
  background-color: #00FFFF;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Is there any solution for that..?

Comment: Can you explain it more?

Comment: I have a div which have some text and having scroll-bar(overflow:scroll is given). I want to change that scroll design, scroll bar color as well.

Answer (score 1):

These are the pseudo elements themselves. The actual parts of the

**CSS**

```
    ::-webkit-scrollbar              { /* 1 */ }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-button       { /* 2 */ }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track        { /* 3 */ }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  { /* 4 */ }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb        { /* 5 */ }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner       { /* 6 */ }
    ::-webkit-resizer                { /* 7 */ }
```

**The Different States**

These are the pseudo class selectors. They allow for more specific selection of the parts, like when the scrollbar is in different states.

**CSS**

```
:horizontal
:vertical
:decrement
:increment
:start
:end 
:double-button
:single-button
:no-button
:corner-present
:window-inactive
```

**:horizontal** – The horizontal pseudo-class applies to any scrollbar pieces that have a horizontal orientation.

**:vertical** – The vertical pseudo-class applies to any scrollbar pieces that have a vertical orientation.

**:decrement** – The decrement pseudo-class applies to buttons and track pieces. It indicates whether or not the button or track piece will decrement the view’s position when used (e.g., up on a vertical scrollbar, left on a horizontal scrollbar).

**:increment** – The increment pseudo-class applies to buttons and track pieces. It indicates whether or not a button or track piece will increment the view’s position when used (e.g., down on a vertical scrollbar, right on a horizontal scrollbar).

**:start** – The start pseudo-class applies to buttons and track pieces. It indicates whether the object is placed before the thumb.

**:end** – The end pseudo-class applies to buttons and track pieces. It indicates whether the object is placed after the thumb.

**:double-button** – The double-button pseudo-class applies to buttons and track pieces. It is used to detect whether a button is part of a pair of buttons that are together at the same end of a scrollbar. For track pieces it indicates whether the track piece abuts a pair of buttons.

**:single-button** – The single-button pseudo-class applies to buttons and track pieces. It is used to detect whether a button is by itself at the end of a scrollbar. For track pieces it indicates whether the track piece abuts a singleton button.

**:no-button** – Applies to track pieces and indicates whether or not the track piece runs to the edge of the scrollbar, i.e., there is no button at that end of the track.

**:corner-present** – Applies to all scrollbar pieces and indicates whether or not a scrollbar corner is present.

**:window-inactive** – Applies to all scrollbar pieces and indicates whether or not the window containing the scrollbar is currently active. (In recent nightlies, this pseudo-class now applies to ::selection as well. We plan to extend it to work with any content and to propose it as a new standard pseudo-class.)

Here I post Simple example:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

In which we'd get this on a simple div with vertically overflowing text:
[image]

You can also get same output in all browser using Jquery [click here](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)